# How To Change The Parameters Of A Function In Real Time With Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, real-time

I'm working on a sound modifier that would:

1) Get inputs from a user (**X,Y**)

2) Apply effects to a predetermined sound file using the **X** and **Y**

The code is a bit hard to follow so I'll not post it unless wanted otherwise.

I have a function called the effectBox.m:

```
function[] = effectBox(x,y)
```

As it's name suggests it applies effects to 10 consecutive sound samples in a for loop.

I want to change the (x,y) each time an event occurs.

I have used the callback:

```
function sounder()
f=figure;
set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@effectBox);
```

When the mouse moves it takes the first X and Y value that triggered the event and applies the effects on all 10 samples. However I want it to change each time the mouse moves again.

In other words sounder.m calls and supplies the first set of inputs for effectBox.m but I want it to be able to do the same even when the code is running.

I have been working on this project for a long time and I really couldn't figure out how to overcome this obstacle. How can I fix this?

Edit: Here is my code THAT WORKS for effectBox.m

```
clc
clear all
%Load Sound File
[ses Fs] = wavread ('C:\Users\Ogulcan\Desktop\Bitirme Projesi\Codes\kravitz.wav');
%Adjust the sound file so that both channels represent a 1-D matrix
leftChannel = ses(:,1);
rightChannel = ses(:,2);
sound = (leftChannel + rightChannel) / 2;



%length of the sample
t=length(sound);
%number of samples
ns=10;
i=1;
per=t/ns;
%Divide the sample into 5 parts and apply vibrato and pitchshift to each sample.
while i<ns;
 global x
 global y
coords = get(0,'PointerLocation');
%the timer object triggers every second. If you need it faster, decrease the value for           
%Period
timerObj = timer('TimerFcn',@timerCallback,'Period', per);
x=coords(1);
y=coords(2);

start(timerObj);

    v=sound(i*t/ns:(i+1)*t/ns);
    e1 = pitchShift(v,1024,256,x/100);


    a=size (e1+1);
    vl = 1:a(2);
    k = vl/5000;
    %The cursors position in the x axis is our input.

    vib= sin(pi*y*k/450);
    %Add the vibrato effect to the sound
    e=(e1.*vib);
    wavplay(10*e,44100);

    if i==9
        i=1;
    end
    i=i+1;
end
```

note: pitchshift is a function that changes the pitch of a given sound file.

Comment: What triggers a call to effectBox? Is it synchronized in some way to your mouse events? If not, then the best thing would be to use a global variable that has the current mouse position (updated by your mouse handler, and referenced whenever effectBox is called); if it is, then you call effectBox from the mouse event handler. Would that work - or did I miss the point of your question completely?

Comment: @Floris The effectBox is triggered by the WindowButtonMotionFcn.If you are referring to the event when the effectBox starts to work. I'm not very good with the terminology. Can you show me an example for this global variable? I'll check it by myself too. Thank you very much for the response.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling your callback function like that. With that, `x` will be your caller's handle and `y` will be eventdata. Do you want to pass user inputs to `effectBox`?

Comment: @HebeleHododo yes I wan't the effectBox take the user inputs in real time and apply it **while** the code is executing. As I've said the closest I've come is: I get the input from user, apply the effects to sound sample and start over next time a new input is given. I don't want the sound sample to be interrupted while the effects are applied.

Comment: I couldn't understand why you used `WindowButtonMotionFcn`. Is `effectBox` where acquisition starts, or where the acquired data is processed?

Answer (score 0):

Having read your comments and code more carefully, there is no need for global variables. Instead, do this:

```
function effectBox(X,Y)
  % whatever code you need here...
```

Setting up the callback:

```
h = figure; % create new figure, get handle
set h, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseMove); % execute mouseMove when mouse moves
```

And the callback looks like this:

```
Function mouseMove()
  C = get (gca, 'CurrentPoint'); % read current position of mouse when it moves
  effectBox( C(1), C(2) ); % calls effectBox with mouse coordinates X,Y
```

Note - I was unable to test this as I'm not near a machine with Matlab license right now. If anything doesn't work as expected please tell me in the comments and I'll help you figure it out.

Comment: @ Floris Thank you for your answer I'm sorry for the late reply. I have tried your suggestion alas, it didn't make any change. The code doesn't work the way I want it to. It doesn't cut the song in the middle it just waits for the loop to end and then it takes the current point. I don't know maybe it's the profile picture but I believe  you can help me, I can post the code if you want.
Nevertheless many thanks to you and all those who replied.

Comment: I see. The problem is that `effectBox` processes a whole file at once; if you call it again, you don't interrupt what you are doing. You will need to show a bit more of what you are doing in effectBox - and yes, we may be back to using global variables if my hunch is right... If I understand your question correction, you need to be able to update the parameters used for processing in the middle of a song. Unless you show the processing of the song in more detail I can't help. But when you do - maybe I can. So yes - post the code; will see what I can do. No promises.

Comment: It worked!! And I didn't need the global variables too! (You can erase them) Thank you very much for the help.
ps. I changed the sound sample from kravitz to "I'm sorry Dave." =)

Comment: "I'm sorry Dave"... you recognized the avatar, then. It's so much better when you end making it work by yourself! Glad it's working now. Did you know it is possible to "accept" an answer (little check mark below the +- voting number)?